# Method ‘FindFirst’ of object ‘Recordset2’ failed. After not saving new record

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a form, create a new record, edit some data but before saving it use a combo box on the form to select another record to navigate to. This triggers the `cboSalePicker_AfterUpdate`. Then during this sub `Form_BeforeUpdate` executes. The user clicks no on the MsgBox to not save the new record. Then the rest of `cboSalePicker_AfterUpdate` is executed however the following error message is displayed:

**Error Message**

```
Error number -2147417848: Method ‘FindFirst’ of object ‘Recordset2’ failed.
```

Associated with the line `Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[SaleID] = " & Str(Nz(cboSalePicker.Value, 0))`

However, if the new record is saved no error is produced and the code performs as expected.

**Form_BeforeUpdate**

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim iResponse As Integer

    'Specify the mesage to display
    strMsg = "Do you wish to save the changes?" & Chr(10)
    strMsg = strMsg & "Click Yes to Save or No to Discard changes."

    'Display the msg box
    iResponse = MsgBox(strMsg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Record?")

    'Check response
    If iResponse = vbNo Then
        'Undo the change.
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
        'Cancel the update
        Cancel = True
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

**cboSalePicker_AfterUpdate**

```
Private Sub cboSalePicker_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "[SaleID] = " & Str(Nz(cboSalePicker.Value, 0))

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are converting Your SaleID into a String using this

```
Str(Nz(cboSalePicker.Value, 0))
```

But your find first is looking for a number. If SaleID *is* a number then remove the Str() function from your code around the combobox value.

To show the concatenation try this

```
  Private Sub cboSalePicker_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim sCriteria as String

    sCriteria = "[SaleID] = " & Nz(Me.cboSalePicker, 0)
    debug.print sCriteria

     Me.Recordset.FindFirst sCriteria

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment out the first error handler line whilst you are debugging things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe DAO.Recordset.FindFirst criteria parameter should be a string type. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao). However, I did try it without the type conversion and unfortunately I still encountered the same error as described above.